# "authClient is not a function" in Electron app

Tags: node.js, google-api, electron, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm relatively new to Electron, and I've been trying to get over this error for the past 5 days. I've tried many of the other posts's answers, but I've had no luck

From the Dev Tools window, I get the error "authClient.request is not a function" whenever the listFiles function is called. The error is thrown at `let res = await drive.files.list`, but I can't get anything to work. I've tried this in a separate nodejs console program, and it's working as expected. Am I missing something?

**main.js**

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const { join } = require("path");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const { OAuth2Client } = require("google-auth-library");
const { authenticate } = require("@google-cloud/local-auth");

function createWindow() {
  const window = new BrowserWindow({
    title: "Cloud Linker 0.3.0",
    titleBarStyle: "hidden",
    titleBarOverlay: {
      color: "#202020",
      symbolColor: "#8f8f8f",
    },
    movable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
    show: false,
    backgroundColor: "#202020",
  });

  window.loadFile(join(__dirname, "./app/index.html"));
  window.webContents.openDevTools();
  window.setMinimumSize(700, 435);
  window.removeMenu();

  window.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
    window.maximize();
  });
}

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});

app.on("ready", () => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
});

ipcMain.handle("getToken", async (event, openConsent) => {
  return await getToken(openConsent);
});

ipcMain.handle("listFiles", async (event, authClient) => {
  return await listFiles(authClient);
});

//
// Google
//

const SCOPES = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
];
const TOKEN_PATH = join(__dirname, "token.json");
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = join(__dirname, "credentials.json");

async function loadToken() {
  try {
    const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, "utf-8");
    const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
    const authToken = google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);

    if (authToken) {
      console.log("Saved credentials found");
      console.log("Saved credentials:", authToken, "\n");
    }

    return authToken;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Saved credentials not found\n");

    return null;
  }
}

async function saveToken(client) {
  try {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
      type: "authorized_user",
      client_id: key.client_id,
      client_secret: key.client_secret,
      refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });

    await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("saveToken error:", err, "\n");
  }
}

async function getToken(openConsent) {
  let client = await loadToken();
  console.log("getToken loadToken client:", client, "\n");
  if (client) return client;

  if (openConsent && !client) {
    client = await authenticate({
      scopes: SCOPES,
      keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });

    if (client.credentials) {
      console.log(
        "getToken openConsent client credemtials:",
        client.credentials,
        "\n"
      );
      await saveToken(client);
    }

    return client;
  }

  return null;
}

async function listFiles(authClient) {
  try {
    const drive = google.drive({
      version: "v3",
      auth: authClient,
    });

    let res = await drive.files.list({
      pageSize: 10,
      fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
    });

    return res.data.files;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("listFiles error:", err, "\n");
  }
}
```